# Custom inventory decrement

Tags: product, inventory, quantity

I have a product that is sold in quantities of 25. If a customer orders one of the product, they actually receive 25.

However, in the warehouse, the product is not packaged in bundles of
25. When a customer places an order for 1, the warehouse ships 25 individual units.

How I can customize my inventory decrement for this product, so when a customer orders 1, the product's inventory count decreases by 25?

My client doesn't want to use the Magento's **Quantity Increments** tool. (For marketing reasons, they want to promote the product as a package and don't want the customer to have to enter "25" as the quantity.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **bundle product** for this purpose.

In the *Bundle Items* section, select your existing product with a *Default Qty* of 25 and set *User Defined Qty* to "No".

[image: bundle selection]

Then, you can set your existing product's *Visibility* to "not visible individually".

[image: visibility]

Now, selling your new bundle product will decrement your existing product's qty by 25.

Comment: Thanks Tim!  I looked all through **bundled product**, but missed the **Defaulty Qty** setting.